# How do i create Addition assignments for every value in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, addition

I have a JComboBox that holds an Enum class with months and a JTextfield(txtHours) for entering amount of workhours done for every month.

I have another JLabel that holds the value for the total of all months below

```
double hours = Double.parseDouble(txtHours.getText());
            
yearHours += hours;
yLabel.setText("Hours this year: " + yearHours);
```

How can i save and update the amount of hours for a specific month so that the label updates itself at runtime depending on which month is chosen from the combobox?

```
 if (e.getSource() == cmbMonths){

       mLabel.setText("Hours for " + cmbMonths.getSelectedItem() +": " + monthHours);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, namely

> How can i save and update the amount of hours for a specific month

I would use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where the `Map` key would be the month and the value would be the total hours worked for that month. In the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html), that was added in Java 1.8, there is a [Month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum so I would use that as the `Map` key.

Rather than using a `JTextField` to enter the hours worked, I would use a [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).

In order to update the total hours worked, I would add a [ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html) to the `JSpinner` model so that each time its value was changed, the text of the `JLabel` displaying total hours worked would get updated so as to display the new total.

The only thing remaining is to add an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to the `JComboBox` such that it displays the entered value for total hours worked whenever the user chooses a particular month.

Here is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class EnumCombo implements ActionListener, ChangeListener, Runnable {
    private Map<Month, Double>  hoursWorked;
    private JComboBox<Month>  monthsCombo;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JLabel  totalHoursLabel;
    private JSpinner  hoursSpinner;

    public EnumCombo() {
        hoursWorked = new HashMap<Month, Double>(12);
        for (Month month : Month.values()) {
            hoursWorked.put(month, Double.valueOf(0));
        }
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JComboBox<?>) {
            JComboBox<?> combo = (JComboBox<?>) source;
            Object obj = combo.getSelectedItem();
            if (obj instanceof Month) {
                Month month = (Month) obj;
                hoursSpinner.setValue(hoursWorked.get(month));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.event.ChangeListener
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if (source instanceof SpinnerNumberModel) {
            SpinnerNumberModel snm = (SpinnerNumberModel) source;
            Object obj = snm.getValue();
            if (obj instanceof Double) {
                Double value = (Double) obj;
                hoursWorked.put((Month) monthsCombo.getSelectedItem(), value);
                Double total = hoursWorked.values()
                                          .stream()
                                          .reduce(Double.valueOf(0),
                                                  (tot, val) -> tot + val);
                totalHoursLabel.setText(total.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JPanel createInputPanel() {
        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel monthLabel = new JLabel("Month");
        inputPanel.add(monthLabel);
        monthsCombo = new JComboBox<Month>(Month.values());
        monthsCombo.addActionListener(this);
        inputPanel.add(monthsCombo);
        JLabel hoursLabel = new JLabel("Hours Worked");
        inputPanel.add(hoursLabel);
        SpinnerNumberModel snm = new SpinnerNumberModel(Double.valueOf(0),
                                                        Double.valueOf(0),
                                                        Double.valueOf(999),
                                                        Double.valueOf(1));
        snm.addChangeListener(this);
        hoursSpinner = new JSpinner(snm);
        inputPanel.add(hoursSpinner);
        return inputPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTotalPanel() {
        JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Total Hours");
        totalPanel.add(label);
        totalHoursLabel = new JLabel("0");
        totalPanel.add(totalHoursLabel);
        return totalPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createInputPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createTotalPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new EnumCombo());
    }
}
```

Note that method `stateChanged`, in the above code, uses the [stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) which was also added in Java 1.8

Here is a screen capture of the running app.

[image: screen capture of running app]